# Time required to fill all cells with infinte number of balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to find an answer to an interesting variation of occupancy problem. Suppose I have infinite number of identical balls at my discretion. I have k identical cells. I keep on placing balls into the cells until all the cells are filled. Each cell can hold any number of balls. What is the expected number of balls required to fill all the cells?

Comment: Are you placing the balls into the cells uniformly at random? If so, this is the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), and the answer is that you should expect to fill the bins after placing around $k\ln k+\gamma k+\frac12$ balls, where $\gamma\approx 0.577\ldots$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).